# files progress dialog minimized (eOS Juno)

Tags: files

Sometime when I copy files interactively using io.elementary.files (either local to to smb/ftp) the copy dialog disappers. When I manage to restore it it is just a little white box so I can't acctually see what's happening or if there are any problems. The file icon in the plank show some (dark) progess bar but the dialog box is just empty.

Comment: Please report this bug to elementary OS developers @ https://github.com/elementary/files/issues

Comment: OK, i created the issue there.